# How to get All Text in robot framework ?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

Consider the following source code,

```
<div id="groupContainer" class="XXXXXX">

<ul id="GroupContactListWrapper" class="list-wrapper">
    <li class="contactNameItemContainer">

        <div class="contactNameItem">
            <span class="name">Name1</span>
        </div>

    </li>
    <li class="contactNameItemContainer">

        <div class="contactNameItem">
            <span class="name">Name2</span>
        </div>

    </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

How do i retreive the two names (Name1,Name2) in a list variable ? 
I tried the following xpath for a "Get Text" keyword, but only returns the first one.

```
//div[@id='groupContainer']//li[@class='contactNameItemContainer']//span
```

Please suggest

Comment: Show the full code you used to 1) retrieve the list, and 2) retrieve the text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could iterate over the elements as below:

```
${xpath}=    Set Variable    //div[@id='groupContainer']//li[@class='contactNameItemContainer']//span
${count}=    Get Matching Xpath Count    ${xpath}
${names}=    Create List
:FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1    ${count} + 1
\    ${name}=    Get Text    xpath=(${xpath})[${i}]
\    Append To List    ${names}    ${name}
```

This works but is rather slow when there are many matches.

Comment: Can I please ask why you used "${name}" as the list name instead of "@{name}"?

Comment: I think there is a typo, **xpath=(${xpath})[${i}]** should have been **xpath=(${xpath})**

Comment: That's why I think RF sucks when a test case  is a little complex. It creates a new language, but make it more complecated and way less powerful than python.  Why doesn't It just let us just use python, and RF, as a framework, just provides functions like machanism of setup, teardown, control test cases scripts running, generator report. That's enough and good.  Now it does more but does bad.  Keyword development sucks.

Answer (score 3):

You could extend `Selenium2Library` and write your own keyword for this purpose. Save the following as `Selenium2LibraryExt.py`

```
from Selenium2Library import Selenium2Library


class Selenium2LibraryExt(Selenium2Library):

    def get_all_texts(self, locator):
        """Returns the text value of elements identified by `locator`.
        See `introduction` for details about locating elements.
        """
        return self._get_all_texts(locator)

    def _get_all_texts(self, locator):
        elements = self._element_find(locator, False, True)
        texts = []
        for element in elements:
            if element is not None:
                texts.append(element.text)
        return texts if texts else None
```

Then you can use your new `Get All Texts` keyword in your tests like this:

```
*** Settings ***
library     Selenium2LibraryExt


*** Test Cases ***
Get All Texts Test
  Open Browser    http://www.example.com   chrome
  @{texts}        Get All Texts            css=.name
  Log Many        ${texts}
```

Answer (score 3):

Though the top-rated answer is fully working - and the most xpath-ish :), let me add an option I don't see proposed yet - using the `Get Webelements` keyword. E.g.:

```
@{locators}=     Get Webelements    xpath=//div[@id='groupContainer']//li[@class='contactNameItemContainer']//span
${result}=       Create List

:FOR   ${locator}   in    @{locators}
\       ${name}=    Get Text    ${locator}
\       Append To List  ${result}  ${name}
```

It'll generate and return a list of all matching elements, on which you just iterate on. It might be a tad faster than xpath's `[index]` reference because the dom is evaluated once - but don't hold me accountable if that's not fully true :)

Answer (score 2):

Get Text will return content of the first element that matches the locator. When using XPATH you can specify the index of the element you want to get, like this:

```
${name1}    Get Text    xpath=//div[@id='groupContainer']//li[@class='contactNameItemContainer'][0]//span
${name2}    Get Text    xpath=//div[@id='groupContainer']//li[@class='contactNameItemContainer'][1]//span
@{names}    Create List    ${name1}    ${name2}
```

Comment: This would work for the above case, but i was looking for a more generic one where there could be more than 2 inner LI containers

Answer (score 2):

@Velapanur

I had another similar requirement where in i have to enter the texts into textareas in a page.
The below i wrote with the idea in reference to what Todor had suggested, and it worked. Many thanks to Todor, Velapanur

```
@{Texts}=    Get WebElements    ${AllTextboxes}

    :FOR    ${EachTextarea}    in    @{Texts}

\    Input Text    ${EachTextarea}    ${RandomTextdata}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the logic to get all elements in Java. You can adopt it to your need.

You have to use findElements() and not findElement() to get all elements.

```
List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul#GroupContactListWrapper div.contactNameItem"));

foreach(item in items){
   System.out.println(item.getText();
}
```

If you want a particular element from the list you can use items.get(1)

Comment: Thanks but was looking for the equivalent in Robot Framework.

Comment: Thanks I already know the logic, just wanted a robot framework implementation.